# Homework question--Critical points of the Logistic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question reads:

> Find and classify the fixed points of $N(t)=r-a(N-b)^2$

My attempt goes:

$r-a(N^2+b^2-2bN) = (N^2r+b^2r-2bNr)+(-aN^2-b^2a+2bNa)$

But I'm not sure how to get the required roots which are supposed to be $x = b\pm\sqrt{\frac{r}{a}}$

Answer (score 1):

The rate of change is $ r-a(N-b)^2$

You need to to solve $$ r-a(N-b)^2=0$$ for $N$

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: (N-b)^2=r/a take square root